# How to Implement ng-model inside ng-repeat for mutilpe textfields in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

This is my code

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = [];

  $scope.data = [{
    "label": "name",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "label": "email",
    "type": "string"
  }];
  $scope.addFields = function() {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(obj) {
      if (count == 2) {
        return true;
      }
      $scope.data.push(obj);
      count = count + 1;
    });
  };
  $scope.save = function() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  };
}
```

```html
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="button" value="add" ng-click="addFields()" />
    <div ng-repeat="eachItem in data">
      <label>{{eachItem.label}}</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="eachItem.value" />
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="save" ng-click="save()" />
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/0c5p38dt/5/
In the above code i have an array with multiple objects, these objects are getting from services dynamically. when i click add button again same objects push to the same array. I use ng-model inside ng-repeat for textfield. But when i enter data that will be effect on other textfields also.So how to differentiate the ng-model value for multiple same objects in array.

Comment: as you said, same objects push to the same array. You are modifying the same object when you enter data, so all fields bound to the same ng-model will be changed as well. In the addField function, if you clone the object, i.e. angular.copy(obj). before push it to the array, you should see the difference. But I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `addFields()` function is not adding fields that have their own objects. It is creating new fields that point to the existing objects.

Essentially, when your `addFields()` is called, it is saying "add two new fields that point to the same object as the first two fields." This is why they all share the same model.

The solution is to actually create a new object that is a clone of the original in the `addFields()` function like so:

```
$scope.addFields = function () {
    var count=0;
    angular.forEach($scope.data,function(obj){
        if(count==2){
            return true;
        }

        // Create a new object with the same properties as the original
        var newObj = {'label':obj.label, 'type':obj.type}
        $scope.data.push(newObj);
        count=count+1;
    });
};
```

I modified your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nhupL4gs/

Comment: Thank You @Richard Pressler. What i Want output you give exact code for that. Thank you very much